# Evaluate trig limit without l'hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I need help evaluating the following limit without using l'Hopital's rule:

$$\lim_{x\to \pi/3} \frac{\sin{x}-\sqrt{3}\cos{x}}{\sin{(x-\pi/3)}}$$

I have tried converting $\sin{(x-\pi/3)}$ to $-\cos{(\pi/6+x)}$ and seeing if I can cancel out terms. I have also tried rationalizing the expression by multiplying both numerator and denominator with $(\sin{x} + \sqrt{3}\cos{x})$. Neither seemed to lead me where I needed and I am out of ideas

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried converting sin (x-pi/3) to -cos(pi/6+x) and seeing if I can cancel out terms. I have also tried rationalizing the expression by multiplying both numerator and denominator with (sinx + v3cosx). Neither seemed to lead me where I needed and I am out of ideas.

Comment: It would be great if you can add this in the question,otherwise the question might attract downvotes,close votes

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll add it

Comment: Even faster. Let $x=y+\frac \pi 3$ and expand the numerator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to \pi/3} \frac{\sin{x}-\sqrt{3}\cos{x}}{\sin{(x-\pi/3)}}$$

note that $$\sin \left(x-\frac{\pi}{3}\right) = \sin x \cos \frac{\pi}{3}-\cos x \sin \frac{\pi}{3}$$

$$\sin \left(x-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=  \frac{1}{2}\sin x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \cos x$$

substitute this in denominator,to get the answer

Comment: Thank you! This solves it. I was not aware of this conversion, but it comes in handy!